# How can I dump my sqlite3 database to SQL in UTF8 with django?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, sqlite

Is there anybody who knows how to solve the next problem?

Right now I am using this code:

```
def databasedump(request):
    # Convert file existing_db.db to SQL dump file dump.sql
    con = sqlite3.connect('database.sqlite')
    with open('dump.sql', 'w') as f:  
        for line in con.iterdump():
            f.write('%s\n' % line)
```

and I get this error:

> Exception Type:
>   UnicodeEncodeError
>
> Exception Value:
>      'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 112: ordinal not in range(128)

The string that could not be encoded/decoded was: (Arivé, PAK

Thanks for looking into this!

Comment: check for this bug: http://bugs.python.org/issue15109

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is  a bug in the `sqlite3` dump code, tracked as [issue 15019](http://bugs.python.org/issue15109) in the Python bug tracker.

You can fix this by editing the `sqlite3/dump.py` file and adding the following line at the top:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

Locate the file by running the following command:

```
python -c 'import sqlite3.dump; print sqlite3.dump.__file__.rstrip("c")'
```

You'll have to adjust the line writing code to encode the unicode values that now will be returned from the `.iterdump()` method:

```
with open('dump.sql', 'w') as f:  
    for line in con.iterdump():
        f.write('%s\n' % line.encode('utf8'))
```

If you feel uncomfortable with editing the Python standard library source files, use the following (fixed and shortened) function instead:

```
def iterdump(connection):
    cu = connection.cursor()
    yield(u'BEGIN TRANSACTION;')

    q = """
        SELECT "name", "type", "sql"
        FROM "sqlite_master"
            WHERE "sql" NOT NULL AND
            "type" == 'table'
        """
    schema_res = cu.execute(q)
    for table_name, type, sql in sorted(schema_res.fetchall()):
        if table_name == 'sqlite_sequence':
            yield(u'DELETE FROM "sqlite_sequence";')
        elif table_name == 'sqlite_stat1':
            yield(u'ANALYZE "sqlite_master";')
        elif table_name.startswith('sqlite_'):
            continue
        else:
            yield(u'{0};'.format(sql))

        table_name_ident = table_name.replace('"', '""')
        res = cu.execute('PRAGMA table_info("{0}")'.format(table_name_ident))
        column_names = [str(table_info[1]) for table_info in res.fetchall()]
        q = """SELECT 'INSERT INTO "{0}" VALUES({1})' FROM "{0}";""".format(
            table_name_ident,
            ",".join("""'||quote("{0}")||'""".format(col.replace('"', '""')) for col in column_names))
        query_res = cu.execute(q)
        for row in query_res:
            yield(u"{0};".format(row[0]))

    q = """
        SELECT "name", "type", "sql"
        FROM "sqlite_master"
            WHERE "sql" NOT NULL AND
            "type" IN ('index', 'trigger', 'view')
        """
    schema_res = cu.execute(q)
    for name, type, sql in schema_res.fetchall():
        yield(u'{0};'.format(sql))

    yield(u'COMMIT;')
```

Use the above like this:

```
con = sqlite3.connect('database.sqlite')
with open('dump.sql', 'w') as f:  
    for iterdump(con):
        f.write('%s\n' % line.encode('utf8'))
```

Comment: Error is on this line: for line in con.iterdump(): Both adding .encode('utf-8') or .decode('utf-8') doesn't change anything.

Comment: @user1826178: Interesting, do you have a more complete traceback?

Comment: @user1826178: ah, I think I see it ([see the [`dump` module source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/457c0c9c7893/Lib/sqlite3/dump.py)); I think you have located a bug in the `sqlite3` codebase, as it *does not handle Unicode data*.

Comment: @user1826178: Updated my answer. In future, include a full traceback for such errors; I made the assumption that the problem was in your code; a full traceback would have made it clear from the start that the error was in the `sqlite3` module codebase instead.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: You are right, next time I will include the full traceback. Thanks for your answer, though. This solution worked for me.